# c# MailMessage dependent on the content of the subject?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, mailmessage

This is weird!
I'm trying to send an email using MailMessage through an SmtpClient and I'm getting some strange results!
Here's what's going on:
1) This works on some emails but not on others.
2) I've narrowed it down to some problems with some subjects (work) and not others (don't work).
For example - a subject of 'Lease has been approved by the land.' works. It's exactly 36 chars long.
   - a subject of 'Landlord approved lease.            ' does not work even though it's exactly 36 chars long.
   - a subject of 'Landlord approved lease.............' does work. It's exactly 36 chars long.

**Why is the Subject sooooo picky?**

I pull the subject lines from a database table. The columns are formatted as an nchar(100) nullable. I Trim() each string before I assign it to the subject line so the width shouldnt make a difference.
Any clues anyone?!

Thanks

Comment: What doesn't work (what error)? Please you include your send mail function. I suspect the length of your subject is not the culprit.

Comment: You may need to set the [SubjectEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.subjectencoding.aspx), but without knowing exactly what error you're getting it's impossible to say.

Comment: have you tried with a local smtp development server like smtp4dev

Comment: There was no error... It just didn't work!

Comment: mMailMessage.Subject = strSubject;
    mMailMessage.Body = strBody;
    mMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

    // Send the message.
    SmtpClient mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient(strHost);
    mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage);

Comment: Here's how that mMailMessage is instantiated. MailMessage mMailMessage = new MailMessage { From = new MailAddress(strFrom) };

Comment: I can't use a local smtp development server because I must use the companies smtp server.

Comment: Works: mailMessage.Subject = (string)(" landlord approved lease branch sessions.").Replace('\r', ' ').Replace('\n', ' ');

Comment: Does not work: mailMessage.Subject = (string)(" landlord approved lease.").Replace('\r', ' ').Replace('\n', ' '); The only difference between these two is the 'Subject' string that works has an appended " branch sessions" at the end. Take that away and no email is sent out.

Comment: If you're not getting an error the problem is likely happening on the server.  You should check the SMTP logs, or possibly check if your "from" account is receiving any bounce back messages from the server.

Comment: No bounce back messages and I'm looking into the SMTP server logs now... It takes our IT department some time on these things. Thanks!

Comment: This is just weird! I GIVE UP!!